# How to change the syntax highlight color in GNU Enscript?

Tags: c, syntax-highlighting, enscript

[GNU Enscript](https://www.gnu.org/software/enscript/) is a free replacement for Adobe enscript program, and I downloaded it for syntax  highlighting and *.ps output, but can I change the default color model? I found that there is a file named `c.st` in `/usr/share/enscript`, but it's just listed about keywords but not their colors.

For example, the keywords such as `int` is green, but I think blue looks better to me.

How to change the syntax highlight color in GNU Enscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the file with the default color definitions is in `/usr/share/enscript/style_ifh.st` -- I believe the line you want to change is:

```
face_keyword[fg_color] =    language_color ("SeaGreen2");
```

File `enscript.st` defines all the color names known to enscript - in my copy, the color definitions are on line 190-221.  Search for `define_color`.